# Problem with particles with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Hair particles are low poly when I try to render particles with cycles, but with Eevee particles are normal.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix I just lowered diameter root setting at Particle properties>Hair shape>Diameter root.